# How to replace spacial character (') to space in php string

Tags: php

I want to replace special character  `single quotes(')` with space . In Java it is easy but i dont know how to do this in php.

Comment: Google: `php replace character` And you'll be back here

Comment: i didnt undustood

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace()` string function in `php`.

Example : `echo str_replace(" ' "," ","India' ");`

Explanation : Here, in `str_replace()` function first argument you need to pass string which you want to replace. For second argument you need to pass string you want to replace with existing. And for third and last argument you need to pass your original string in which you need replace.

Comment: Here if str_replace() find multiple occurrence of your search string then also it will replace with white space.

Comment: For more details you can review this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $data = str_replace("'", " ", string);
      echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: if multiple '' will replace

Comment: multiple like ?

Answer (score 0):

to remove just single quote :

```
$FileName = str_replace("'", " ", string);
```

to remove other characters as well, use array :

```
$remove[] = "'";
$remove[] = '"';
$remove[] = "-"; // just as another example

$FileName = str_replace( $remove, " ", string);
```